# UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView r

Tags: android

I have a problem with date picker in my project.
I get error:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker
            at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.getCalendarView(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:498)
            at android.widget.DatePicker.getCalendarView(DatePicker.java:377)
            at jadezabiore.spot.pl.jadezabiorepl.dialogs.DialogWithCalendar$1.onClick(DialogWithCalendar.java:56)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

only for lilipop system. There is any way to handle that?

Edit:
This is problematic code:

```
 IDatePickerInFilter act = (IDatePickerInFilter) activity;
                datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
                act.getDateDialog(new DateToTimestampConverter().getStringDateFromTimestamp(datePicker.getCalendarView().getDate()));
```

Comment: what's your code? what have you tried?

Comment: By default, datePickerMode is spinner, after API 21 you can't get CalendarView if you use spinner mode.

Comment: @calvinfly so how can I resolve my problem?

Comment: are you using spinner mode or calendar?

Comment: sorry, i was wrong.....in calendar mode, DatePicker.getCalendarView() would return Exception in post API 21, you may use if-case to handle API level larger than or equal to 21

Comment: yes! i change in xml on "spinner" and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To save some time for others like me, as mentioned by @calvinfly:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
    // e.g. datePicker.getCalendarView() ...
} else {
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is - how to get the selected date since API 21. Pre-21 a frequent approach was to use the `CalendarView`, API 21+ the only possible way seems to provide `OnDateChangedListener` in `DataPicker` `init` method.

```
datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, 
        int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // do the date stuff
    }
});
```

The error message is also a bit too cryptic - "new DatePicker" refers not to a new DatePicker object (so you could expect to be able to init the view), but to the new version of DatePicker available since API 21 (that throws an error whenever you ask for the `CalendarView`).